# Swift Storyboard List view Not Working?

Tags: ios, swift, listview, storyboard

Been following tutorials online to create a scrollable list view in the storyboard.

I have done the following

View Controller --> Scroll View --> Content View

The scroll view is constrained to the View controller.
The content view width is constrained to the View controller.

The contentSize is set to 1000 height for the content view.
The story board is set to 1000 height.
The scroll view is set to 1000 height.

It appears to only scroll down half way

Any ideas on what i have done wrong here

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the height constraint for the scrollview, and fix it to the bottom of your parent view.